# Why adding a fixed position and translateY negative appears top 0 then hides?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a header ([comparable to MailChimp's](http://connect.mailchimp.com/)) but instead of if being fixed all the time, I want the header to scroll up with the page and only drop down once the user has made an upward scrolling motion.

I have this working at present by adding a class that has `postion: fixed;` and then applying `transform: translateY(-50px);` to position the header off screen. Here's the trick, when this happens, the `postion: fixed;` starts at what appears to be `top: 0;` and therefore shows itself before sliding up (I have a transition on the top to slide it up gracefully). Anyone know how I can force the header to start off canvas and then go transition to `transform: translateY(0);` when I queue it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanshrum/Lds3e/)

Comment: You mean like a slide back in? Can you create a fiddle or something to visualize it better? Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uy8He/)?

Comment: I updated my question with a link to a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ryanshrum/Lds3e/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, this may be the solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/wGh9E/2/)
I changed plenty of lines because I think it's easier.

1. Gave header .fixed class in the markup and removed it from JS (because you can translate it without removing the positioning)
2. Inserted function to detect scroll direction:
3. Removed transform from fixed class since the initial value is zero
4. Put all together into `$(window).scroll()`

```js
var scrolled;
var lastPos = 0;
var $header = $('.main-header');
var scrollDirection;

// on scroll, let the interval function know the user has scrolled
$(window).scroll(function() {

    scrollDirection = getScrollDirection();
    lastPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if(lastPos >= 400 && scrollDirection == "down") {
        $header.addClass("hidden");
    } else if(scrollDirection == "up") {
        $header.removeClass("hidden");
    }

});

function getScrollDirection() {
    if(lastPos >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
        return "up";
    } else {
        return "down";
    }
}
```

```css
.main-header {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 56px;
 z-index: 2;
 background: black;
 -moz-transition: all 500ms;
 -o-transition: all 500ms;
 -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
 transition: all 500ms;
}

.main-header.hidden {
 -moz-transform: translateY(56px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-56px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-56px);
 transform: translateY(-56px);
 position: fixed;
}

.main-header.fixed {
 position: fixed; 
}

div {
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header class="main-header fixed"></header> 
 <div class="hipsum"><p>Keytar sriracha direct trade, you probably haven't heard of them put a bird on it Odd Future farm-to-table gastropub XOXO tousled PBR hashtag viral gentrify polaroid.  Paleo deep v skateboard pug polaroid readymade, tofu Pinterest pork belly crucifix Etsy Echo Park gluten-free Banksy Neutra.  +1 irony YOLO gluten-free PBR Austin Brooklyn drinking vinegar.  Fingerstache ethnic aesthetic, beard Schlitz XOXO pop-up wayfarers Tonx normcore cornhole tattooed you probably haven't heard of them whatever.  Stumptown actually banh mi, Echo Park cornhole beard Tonx flannel Helvetica.  Truffaut selfies ethnic pop-up biodiesel, stumptown master cleanse four loko freegan letterpress Thundercats hoodie fap ethical fanny pack.  PBR&amp;B Odd Future sriracha forage.</p><p>Polaroid Brooklyn Odd Future, photo booth Kickstarter bicycle rights ethnic leggings fanny pack viral tattooed 3 wolf moon bitters hoodie.  Swag tousled Godard messenger bag.  Organic irony gentrify, High Life synth typewriter vegan +1 freegan swag farm-to-table tote bag.  Whatever wayfarers raw denim, fashion axe mumblecore narwhal drinking vinegar pour-over selvage PBR chillwave locavore salvia distillery.  Kogi hoodie disrupt Godard.  PBR&amp;B pork belly literally, ennui Cosby sweater paleo dreamcatcher Neutra kitsch hella YOLO.  Brunch jean shorts chia ethical viral twee.</p><p>Banjo distillery Vice, Tonx selfies leggings narwhal tote bag ethnic chambray mustache gluten-free.  Wes Anderson wolf umami +1.  Williamsburg cliche occupy four loko.  Vinyl Shoreditch 90's bicycle rights photo booth, vegan asymmetrical Brooklyn normcore actually locavore.  Drinking vinegar selvage cray Schlitz, ethical selfies 3 wolf moon Vice fashion axe vegan VHS bitters plaid.  Intelligentsia McSweeney's retro, squid tousled actually 8-bit.  Intelligentsia gentrify hella farm-to-table Pitchfork asymmetrical.</p><p>Fanny pack lomo Cosby sweater iPhone kogi wolf, selvage 3 wolf moon 8-bit banh mi tote bag chillwave Tonx try-hard.  Seitan blog fixie put a bird on it tattooed, forage chambray chillwave scenester keytar umami street art +1.  Craft beer before they sold out direct trade  chambray biodiesel.  Typewriter Brooklyn leggings, tattooed PBR fingerstache chambray cred gastropub photo booth roof party synth distillery banjo tousled.  Pug retro swag normcore Schlitz, biodiesel 90's craft beer selfies lomo.  Portland stumptown beard master cleanse normcore.  Butcher four loko Echo Park kale chips church-key fanny pack.</p><p>Marfa fanny pack flannel, cliche lo-fi YOLO kitsch.  Pinterest mumblecore next level banh mi try-hard mlkshk, irony before they sold out chia fap lo-fi semiotics direct trade  Wes Anderson.  Hella craft beer disrupt, pug +1 sustainable paleo locavore meggings.  Banh mi selvage freegan bespoke, direct trade  Bushwick skateboard roof party farm-to-table typewriter McSweeney's mustache.  Slow-carb bespoke Neutra literally Carles authentic XOXO.  Ethical 90's organic wolf skateboard post-ironic try-hard Pitchfork, Neutra locavore XOXO banh mi lomo roof party swag.  Kickstarter tattooed small batch, wayfarers beard Vice McSweeney's put a bird on it post-ironic squid viral ethical Cosby sweater.</p><p>Single-origin coffee swag biodiesel brunch.  Blog Austin whatever drinking vinegar mustache, twee Bushwick gentrify seitan skateboard polaroid Pinterest disrupt next level 8-bit.  Portland biodiesel selvage trust fund bicycle rights.  Photo booth fingerstache bitters, lomo scenester typewriter normcore Austin.  Bushwick Intelligentsia iPhone, Thundercats 8-bit fingerstache Neutra sustainable Echo Park cardigan locavore Odd Future drinking vinegar.  Paleo street art next level, twee fap +1 organic post-ironic beard banjo blog dreamcatcher.  Master cleanse salvia Helvetica normcore bespoke sartorial, McSweeney's cliche authentic street art.</p><p>XOXO flannel chia, ennui Tumblr Truffaut Marfa 90's artisan mustache fashion axe tousled.  Meh fanny pack Echo Park you probably haven't heard of them art party keytar, blog street art gastropub chia.  Typewriter cliche flannel beard banjo, fanny pack gluten-free cardigan wayfarers Tumblr four loko scenester American Apparel.  Aesthetic Wes Anderson sustainable flexitarian, Thundercats retro scenester art party chillwave.  Drinking vinegar VHS trust fund, readymade normcore XOXO irony fingerstache YOLO banjo sriracha jean shorts Odd Future PBR&amp;B chia.  Roof party authentic vegan put a bird on it, Williamsburg Schlitz keytar seitan deep v letterpress sartorial Pitchfork Tonx.  Selvage semiotics 3 wolf moon Portland VHS.</p><p>Chillwave beard sriracha trust fund, Schlitz authentic flannel asymmetrical mumblecore ethnic stumptown.  Austin cliche synth yr, XOXO next level before they sold out High Life 8-bit readymade iPhone Thundercats typewriter meh cardigan.  Authentic ennui Banksy plaid.  Fap Neutra banh mi skateboard, Banksy blog meh Pitchfork photo booth Tumblr four loko.  Slow-carb roof party ethnic Banksy PBR meggings.  Mlkshk semiotics actually Helvetica.  Aesthetic direct trade  four loko 90's dreamcatcher forage, pug Pinterest pickled cardigan put a bird on it wayfarers distillery Tumblr.</p></div>
</body>
```

If you have any questions, just ask.

Comment: I checked out your fiddle. I want the header to scroll with the page initially, then slide down on a scroll up. Your fiddle has it sliding up on scroll (which is a different rate than the page scroll). Any ideas there?

Comment: Thanks for this. 1.) the header is still staying fixed initially. I want it to start absolute so it scrolls with the page, then scroll down. 2.) there is a weird thing happening with the scroll bar once the header hides; it's jumping around.

Comment: I'm not that good in English. But I think I got your point now: [http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/wGh9E/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/wGh9E/5/)
But I can't reproduce the second point - I may have fixed it already.